# Makefile does not create dependency unless manually specified

Tags: compilation, makefile, dependencies

I have a makefile that contains something like this:

```
OSM_BUNDLER_DEP_DIR=osm-bundler-read-only/osm-bundler/software
OSM_BUNDLER_DEPS=$(OSM_BUNDLER_DEP_DIR)/pmvs/bin/pmvs2
CMVS_DIR=CMVS-PMVS/build/main
PMVS_EXE=$(CMVS_DIR)/pmvs2
OSM_BUNDLER_PMVS_DIR=$(OSM_BUNDLER_DEP_DIR)/pmvs/bin

all: $(OSM_BUNDLER_DEPS)

$(OSM_BUNDLER_PMVS_DIR)/pmvs2: $(PMVS_EXE) $(OSM_BUNDER_PMVS_DIR)
    cp $(PMVS_EXE) $(OSM_BUNDLER_PMVS_DIR)

$(OSM_BUNDLER_PMVS_DIR): $(OSM_BUNDLER_DEP_DIR)
    mkdir -p $(OSM_BUNDLER_PMVS_DIR)

$(OSM_BUNDLER_DEP_DIR): osm-bundler-read-only
    mkdir osm-bundler-read-only/osm-bundler/software

osm-bundler-read-only:
    svn checkout http://osm-bundler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ osm-bundler-read-only
```

I would expect `make` to recognize that $(PATH_TO_ANOTHER_DIRECTORY) has to exist before the recipe for `$(PATH_TO_ANOTHER_DIRECTORY)/subpackage` can be executed. Instead, it tries to execute the recipe for the rule `$(PATH_TO_ANOTHER_DIRECTORY)` without doing the recipe for `$(PATH_TO_ANOTHER_DIRECTORY)` first, resulting in an error. Interestingly enough, I can execute the rule to create the directory manually and everything works fine:

```
me@localhost:~/workdir> # make does not recognize dependency
me@localhost:~/workdir> make
cp CMVS-PMVS/build/main/pmvs2 osm-bundler-read-only/osm-bundler/software/pmvs/bin
cp: cannot create regular file ‘osm-bundler-read-only/osm-bundler/software/pmvs/bin’: No such file or directory
make: *** [osm-bundler-read-only/osm-bundler/software/pmvs/bin/pmvs2] Error 1
me@localhost:~/workdir> # Specifying the dependency works
me@localhost:~/workdir> make osm-bundler-read-only/osm-bundler/software/pmvs/bin
mkdir -p osm-bundler-read-only/osm-bundler/software/pmvs/bin
me@localhost:~/workdir> # Now it executes fine
me@localhost:~/workdir> make
cp CMVS-PMVS/build/main/pmvs2 osm-bundler-read-only/osm-bundler/software/pmvs/bin
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example works fine for me, so when you say _something like this_ obviously it's not close enough like it: your real makefile is doing something different which is causing the problem.  My suspicion is you've typo-d the name of the `PATH_TO_ANOTHER_DIRECTORY` variable in the prerequisite list for `$(PATH_TO_ANOTHER_DIRECTORY)/subpackage`.

Comment: You're right, I was trying to provide a more general, minimally runnable example. I've updated to show the real code.

Comment: As I suspected, you have a typo.  In your rule for `$(OSM_BUNDLER_PMVS_DIR)/pmvs2` you list the prerequisite `$(OSM_BUNDER_PMVS_DIR)`, that should be *BUNDLER* not *BUNDER*

Comment: Oh wow, that'S a really stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing it out though :) I'll try to live through the embarassment!